# Odd result after ajax call. Domain type changes when passed to gsp and weird js syntax error. Grails 2.3.7

Tags: ajax, grails

I have a template that renders all of a hasMany property of a domain object (we'll call them foos, even though I pity the foo) as well as the remaining number of those foos that arent included in the domain. From the template you can add or remove foos from the relationship using plus and minus buttons via ajax calls. However...I am getting some pretty strange behavior.

The first time one of the plus or minus buttons is clicked, the ajax call works fine and the model is updated as it should be...but after that, everything breaks. The template gets rendered again as it should but the domain seems to be missing in action (along with its foos) and the buttons no longer work. The foos do get added/removed from the domain and saved correctly, but it's not reflected in the freshly rendered template.

While debugging I decided to simply display the domain objects toString() inside the template and discovered that after the first ajax call it's actually changing from type Domain to type org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade. WEIRD.

Also after trying to click a plus or minus button again, a mysterious syntax error appears in the javascript console:  'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,'    (index):1. The really weird part is where its located....line one of the document, in the DOCTYPE declaration..I inspected it, there is no ',' in there like the SyntaxError says there is, yet the  element still has the dreaded red squiggly line under it.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction here? I've been stuck trying to figure this out for two days!

**Edit**: It's worth noting that I have another part of my application that works exactly like this but with different domain classes, and it works just fine.. I've pretty much spent the past two days making sure that they are exactly the same in every way except for which domains are being used....which only adds to the mystery of this not working.

Domain.groovy

```
class Domain {
    static hasMany = [foos: Foo]
}
```

Foo.groovy

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [domains: Domain]
    static belongsTo = [Domain]
}
```

DomainController.groovy

```
def show(String id) {  
    Domain domain = domain.get(id)

    if (!domain) {
        response.sendError(404)
        return
    }
    [domain: domain, foos: Foo.list() - domain.foos] 
}

def fooToggle(String domainId, String fooId, String fooAction) {
    Domain domain = Domain.get(domainId)
    Foo foo = Foo.get(fooId)

     if (!domain || !foo) {
        response.sendError(404)
        return
     }
     else {  
        if (fooAction == "add") {
            domain.addToFoos(foo)
        }
        else if (fooAction == "remove") {
            domain.removeFromFoos(foo)
        }
        domain.save()
     }

    render template: "foos", model: [domain: domain, foos: Foo.list() - domain.foos]
}
```

show.gsp

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="foos">
        <g:render template="foos" model="${[domain: domain, foos: foos]}" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

_foos.gsp

```
<!-- this is where the type of Domain changes to org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade -->
<g:if test="${domain}">${domain}</g:if>

<g:if test="${domain.foos}">
    <small>Click the minus button to remove a foo from this domain</small>
    <g:each var="foo" in="${domain.foos}">
    <div id="foo${foo.id}" class="fooItem">
        <span>${foo.bar}</span>
        <img onclick="fooToggle(${domain.id}, ${foo.id}, 'remove')" class="fooButton" src="${fam.icon(name: 'delete')}"/>
    </div>
    </g:each>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <p><small><em>This domain does not have any foos</em></small></p>
</g:else>

<g:if test="${foos}">
    <hr>
    <small>Click the plus button to add a foo to this domain</small>
    <g:each var="foo" in="${foos}">
    <div id="foo${foo.id}" class="fooItem">
        <span>${foo.bar}</span>
        <img onclick="fooToggle(${domain.id}, ${foo.id}, 'add')" class="fooButton" src='${fam.icon(name: 'add')}'/>
    </div>
    </g:each>
</g:if>

<script>
function fooToggle(domainId, fooId, fooAction) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${g.createLink(controller: 'domain', action: 'fooToggle')}',
        data: {
            'domainId': domainId,
            'fooId': fooId,
            'fooAction': fooAction
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#foo" + fooId).fadeOut("fast", function() {
                $("#foos").html(resp);
            }); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: `... but the domain seems to be missing in action ...`: Well, you're not passing the right parameter name in your AJAX call. The controller is expecting `domainId` but you're giving it `id`.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ this was a typo. I just fixed it. Just a translation error when I changed it from my actual code to the foo/bar style. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: D'oh, and I thought I might have had it figured out! ;)

Comment: },
        success: function(resp) { console.log(resp); .... try to see what is coming back infact consolg.log url and go to in the browser find out what is going on within the output.. also put printlns in fooToggle to see what is going in that way too and println what is expected to be sent.. ensure all that is good

Comment: @vahid nothing is happening in the success function because the ajax call never even happens because of the 'syntax error'. In fooToggle everything seems to be working and the outputs are as expected up until it renders the gsp page.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Just incase you are curious, I have posted the solution.

Comment: @vahid Just incase you are curious, I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `application` is a JSP implicit object. `Domain.groovy` in my example is in fact actually named `Application.groovy`, and the related variables in `_foos.gsp` are indeed named `application`. Changing the name of the variables to `app` (or any non-reserved variable name) was the solution.

[List of JSP Implicit Objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm)

Comment: hah, well when I saw foo in the example I thought Domain was also an example name rather than actual name..

Comment: @vahid Yea it was. If I would have just used the actual name of Application, someone would have probably been able to help me :D